# How to write a triangle area and perimeter

Tags: javascript, function

I am so new to programming, and I need you all to check my code, why it doesn't work in my chrome browser at all.

I have used a simple html file to call the javascript file, but nothing happens in my chrome browser.

```js
function myFunction(a, b, c) {

  var d = a + b + c;
  return d;

}

var x = myFunction(10, 15, 20);

alert(x);
```

What I want is the input number for a and b, so that the functions will show me the result of the area and the perimeter of a triangle.

Comment: How are you calling this javascript?

Comment: How'bout the other browsers?

Comment: You code is fine, but where is the rest of the code? What’s in you html?

Comment: How are you injecting your javascript code? are you using a script-tag inside your html, are you using a seperate file where you have written your code,... ?

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <title>Simple Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>This is a very simple HTML page</p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong in your code. You could try to use DevTools of Chrome by pressing Ctrl+Shift+I and watch 'Console' tab to check if there's no errors or bugs in your html-code. Perhaps it simply doesn't load the script

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in your script, if you click "run code snippet" you should get the desired output in an alert.

If it isn't working in your local environment then something else is not working, maybe the path to the JS is wrong. Or something else is blocking the script from running. You can debug this with the browser developer tools (F12 or Ctrl + Shift I, depending on the browser)

```js
function myFunction(a, b, c) {

  var d = a + b + c;
  return d;

}

var x = myFunction(10, 15, 20);

alert(x);
```